# How to reach limit of 150MB to release app?

Tags: android, google-play, filesize

We want to release an app in the play store, but the .aab-file is too big. They say our app has to have a limit of 150MB, but our prototype on our smartphone is around 500MB. We already shrunk our images to 1/10 of the normal resolution. How do we have to shrink our app even more?

Comment: I think many apps 'download content' the first time they're launched after installing.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It means that you shall divide the content of your application into chunks and you make the user download on the play store just a little part of the content and then in the first run you're going to make the download the remaining part